# Es6 classes late static binding

Tags: ecmascript-6

Is there late static binding in es6 classes.(without hacks)

For example:

```
class Base {
    static make() {
        return new  ....
    }
}

class Implementation1 extends Base {}

class Implementation2 extends Base{}
```

Basically I want to set base static methods in the base class and do this:

```
Implementation1::make(); Implementation2::make();
```

Without copying the method in each class.

The alternative in PHP is:

```
return new static();
```

Comment: They already are. I copy-pasted your code, replaced `return new  ....` by `return new String("foobar")`, and then ran `Implementation1.make()`, and it returned `String {"foobar"}`. Works like a charm.

Comment: I meant when I call Implementation1::make() to return new instance of Implementation1 class and the same for Implementation2 class - to be dynamic.

Comment: Late binding uses the `this` keyword in JavaScript methods - in static ones as well.